# Concatenating MaTeX with a computable expression in PlotLabel

Tags: plotting, matex

To produce a graphics grid, I would like the `PlotLabel` to be a concatenation of graphics such as `"y="//MaTeX` and the value of an expression like `f[i,j]`, the latter value depending on the values of the indices `i,j` indexing pictures in the graphics grid. So, if e.g. `f[3,2]=0.7`, then the desired label for the picture in row 3 and column 2 of the grid should be `"y=0.7"//MaTeX`.

Or, rather, I would like the PlotLabel to be two such concatenations put one above the other -- or maybe one to the right of the other, with the two concatenations separated by a comma.

Can this be done?

---

To clarify, the command `MaTeX` that is a part of the `PlotLabel` command occurs in a module, say

```
plot[i_,j_]:=Module[{...}, ..., MaTeX[...]; ...]
```

and the function `f[i_,j_]` is defined outside the module `plot[i_,j_]` or, anyway, outside the `PlotLabel` command. The command `plot[i_,j_]` is then used to produce a graphics grid, where the indices `i,j` index the pictures in the grid.

The value of `f[i,j]` must be computed inside the `PlotLabel` command, depending on the values of `i,j` that `plot[i_,j_]` receives. I have tried, naively, to write things like `PlotLabel->"y=f[i,j]"//MaTeX`, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either construct an expression in `HoldForm`,

```
MaTeX@With[{rhs = 0.7}, HoldForm[y = rhs]]
```

[image: MaTeX output]

or construct the TeX code directly.

```
MaTeX@With[{rhs = 0.7}, "y=" <> ToString[rhs, TeXForm]]
```

[image: MaTeX output]